# Angular 5 Service Workers Cache refresh on data update or insertion

Tags: angular-cli, angular5, angular-service-worker

I have been reading about the new Service Workers support for Angular 5 and Angular CLI and I found it fascinating. I'm particularly interested in caching API end points. In all the tutorials I have read, they all seem to focus on caching end point calls once and then serving future requests from the cache storage. What if my web application frequently updates or inserts data? All my requests would still continue being served from the cache which will result in fetching old data and not the new data that I just updated or inserted which would only be retrieved if I make a new call to the API end point. How can we keep this in sync?

To make my question a bit clear; In short what I am asking for is how can you refresh your cache based on your need.I understand that If I pick 'freshness' strategy, it will always fetch from network except at the time of network failure or time out in which case it defaults to the cache. If I pick 'performance' strategy, it will always serve from cache and will not be suitable for things that change often. What I'm looking for is a little bit of both. I would like it to always serve from the cache except in the case where I specifically tell it not to. For example when I create new customer, I would like to refresh the cache and then it continues to serve from the cache until I tell it to refresh otherwise.

Comment: Check this page: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-5-service-worker-b722e571e306 

There is a section "Caching Content From External APIs" that might help you.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I see that it's one alternative

Comment: can't you use freshness strategy of datagroup in ngsw-config.json?

Comment: @BoradAkash I have edited the question to explain in more detail. It wasn't very clear at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

First things first:

Service workers are not able to cache all requests (as of the date of this answer). They can only cache GET requests, since POST requests are inherently meant to change the state of the back-end model. If you are interested in buffering other than GET requests while offline (and then replay them once the internet is reconnected), try [reading here](https://medium.com/web-on-the-edge/offline-posts-with-progressive-web-apps-fc2dc4ad895). The discussion about allowing the service workers to cache POST requests is still ongoing though.

That being said, if your app uses only GETs to populate the app state in the browser, it will work just fine offline (once a user accesses all the GETs at least once so they will have been cached).

This caching mechanic is not turned on by default. You have to modify your `ngsw-config.json` to set it up. For `API` request caching, the `dataGroups` is the right place to put the configuration to.

```
"dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api",
      "urls": [
        "https://api.yourdomain.com/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "freshness",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "1d",
        "version": 1
      }
    }
  ]
```

Notice the `strategy` part of the `cacheConfig`. This is what tells the service worker how to behave. In the example, you can see I set it to `freshness`. This means the worker will first try to access the internet and fetch fresh data. If it fails, it will serve the cached version (if there is some). The other allowed value is `performance` which will first serve the cached data (if any) and then sync the cache online in the background.

You can find more on service worker configuration [in the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config)

Comment: Thank you for your response and detailed explanation but my question is specific to only caching get requests. In short what I was asking for was how can you refresh your cache based on your need. Suppose I’m caching customer information (GetCustomerInfo api request) and at latter stage I had registered a new customer and at this specific point I wanted to refresh the cache by calling the get api. How can that be achieved?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there is nothing else you have to do for this to work. You would just pick one of the strategies mentioned (`freshness` / `performance`) and any new request shall refresh the cache for you automatically...

Comment: In case you need more granular control over the caching mechanism, you can build your own service worker script.https://googlechromelabs.github.io/sw-toolbox/ is a great place to start.

Comment: Let me try to put this this way; I understand that If I pick 'freshness' strategy, it will always fetch from network except at the time of network failure or time out in which case it defaults to the cache. If I pick 'performance' strategy, it will always serve from cached data and will not be suitable for things that change often. What I'm looking for is a little bit of both. I would like it to always serve from the cache except in the case where I specifically tell it not to.

Comment: For example when I create new customer, I would like to refresh the cache and then it continues to serve from the cache until I tell it to refresh otherwise. Does that sound feasible?

Comment: Well, the `performance` strategy could be the thing for you in case you are able to deal with the fact that the users will be 1 version late for the first request they make. Conversely, you could try to work around this by setting up the different patterns for the URLs - you can have more `dataGroups`, one for `performance`, one for `freshness`, and call different routes (pointing to the same data) based on what you need.

Comment: I too am fascinated by the difference Service Workers can make for my end users, but I also find the ability for data caching to be quite inflexible.  Currently, I wrote my own in-memory caching where my angular services are singleton instances and I update the cached lists when necessary, i.e. add/remove/replace.  Perhaps this will change in the future, but right now the available configurations for data caching are limited.

Comment: @Jason Baley That’s exactly what I’m looking for in Angular Service Workers; the ability to update caches at any time while still using performance strategy to always refer the cache by default.

Comment: @Heehaaw That still won’t satisfy my need. I want to be able to always use cache and update it whenever necessary which mixing both strategies won’t seem to solve.

Comment: @Eliyah Yeah, we're outta luck... for now, at least.  My own in-memory caching works great, and if I wanted to persist the caches, I could use local storage.  I can still use the service workers for caching the app version, but the out-of-the-box data caching is not real useful right now.

Comment: Yep, you can write your own service worker to manage the cache in any way you want... Or make a custom implementation as @Jason Baley suggests.

Comment: @Eliya, what i think you are looking for is the Background sync. This issue is tracking this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22145

Comment: The question is asking for a way to update the Cache (originally created by a GET) since a POST changed the data on the server.  A calculated value for the cache should be update the cache.  Otherwise a refresh (when offline) will lose the edits made by the POST.